# ASP.NET CSHTML Attaching SQL Connection

Tags: c#, html, sql-server

After so many projects done using standard SQL Connection, i.e

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

I am now moving towards attaching an SQL Connections to the project itself.

[image]

In a standard SQL Connection, I understand how to open/close or use 'using' for the SQL connection, attach/create an adapter and fill a DataSet based on that adapter as well as move the Data in DataSet to a DataTable to be used by a DataView.

i.e.

```
using (SqlConnection appCon = new SqlConnection(DNCS))
            {
                LMTF.LogMessageToFile("DB Connected Successfully");
                SqlDataAdapter transDA2 = new SqlDataAdapter(DNST, appCon);
                HRDevs = new DataSet();
                transDA2.Fill(HRDevs, "HRDevices");
                HRDT = (HRDevs.Tables[0].DefaultView).ToTable();
                try
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in HRDT.Rows)
                    {
                        HRDevice = row["HRDevices"].ToString();
                        HRDName = row["HRDName"].ToString();
                        LMTF.LogMessageToFile("Found a device with serial : " + HRDevice + " , Belongs to property : " + HRDName);
                    }
                }
                catch(System.Exception ex)
                {
                    LMTF.LogMessageToFile("Unable to determine HR Devices from DB. Error is : " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Now, my problem is, I don't understand how this is all done when I attach the SQL to the Project itself as per picture above.

I do know that the DataSet in the Attached SQL contains the Table , the AdapterName and also the Method Name.

But how do I use these Query Name? How do I call these adapters or use the Method Name to return the Values it hold? How do I call the SQL Connection name for attached SQL? This confuses me a lot.

Can anyone guide me to the correct path?

Also is there a difference in doing Standard SQL Connection to Attaching the SQL to the project?

[image]

Edit 1 :

This is an attached DataSet in my project.
[image]

Comment: That connection is not attached to your project. It's just a useful view of the database in your server explorer. It's a GUI tool for your convenience, instead of having to switch to SSMS. It's part of visual studio, not part of the application you are writing. Your code knows nothing about it. Your code can connect to the database in the normal way using a connection string.

Comment: Ah.. No wonder when i try to call the method , it does not work at all. As for my mere understanding , upon attaching it to VS , the connection is already open for my application. What about the DataSet item that i attached to my Project? I will create an Edit for you to see. Name Edit1.

Comment: " upon attaching it to VS , the connection is already open for my application" ...no. Your application executes separately. Think about it...when you deploy your code to be a live application, it no longer has any link to Visual Studio. It's out there on its own. So it would make no sense for it to depend on a component inside Visual Studio. You may be using GUI tools to drag things like datasets into your application, but all that is doing is providing a graphical way to auto-generate some code. In the end that code must still be able to execute independently.

Comment: Besides, the dataset editor is another design-time tool. So yes it can connect to the database via the Connection object in Server Explorer, but that has nothing to do with your application, because the application does not execute the designer code when it runs. Instead it uses the dataset created by it (i.e. the _result_ of using the designer) as part of the application. That dataset, in the context of your running application, needs to connect again to the database in order to fill with data. It does that using the standard connection string in your config file.

Comment: Summary: Don't confuse the tools you're using the build the application with the actual finished application itself. All that these tools do is make it easier to write and generate your application's code. You could write exactly the same application completely by hand using Notepad, if you wanted to. And you could compile and execute it using command-line tools, without any need for Visual Studio.

Comment: @ADyson - Great! this answers my question then. Thank you dear Sir! You have enlighten a soul today with a smile on his face. May i post your comment as answer?

Comment: sure, if you can make a coherent summary of what I've written then please go ahead :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tldr:`
That connection is **not** attached to your project.

---

The connection you can see is just a useful view of the database in your server explorer. It's a GUI tool for your convenience, instead of having to switch to SSMS. It's part of visual studio, not part of the application you are writing. Your code knows nothing about it.

Your application must still connect to the database in the normal way using a connection string when it is executing.

This is because your application executes separately from Visual Studio. Think about it...when you deploy your code to be a live application, it no longer has any link to Visual Studio. It's out there on its own. So it would make no sense for it to depend on a component inside Visual Studio. You may be using GUI tools to drag things like datasets into your application, but all that is doing is providing a graphical way to auto-generate some code. In the end that code must still be able to execute independently.

The Dataset editor you mentioned is another design-time tool. So yes it can connect to the database via the Connection object in Server Explorer, but that has nothing to do with your application, because the application does not execute the designer code when it runs. Instead it uses the dataset created by it (i.e. the *result* of using the designer) as part of the application. That dataset, in the context of your running application, needs to connect again to the database in order to fill with data. It does that using the standard connection string in your config file.

---

Summary:

Don't confuse the tools you're using the build the application with the actual finished application itself. All that these tools do is make it easier to write and generate your application's code. You could write exactly the same application completely by hand using Notepad, if you wanted to. And you could compile and execute it using command-line tools, without any need for Visual Studio.